# How to make a bar graph using select values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been struggling to create what I think should be an easy bar graph. I want to make a bar graph using **ggplot** of Yes or No Deals using only the outliers that I found from my other variable, netprofits by using

```
data_2$netprofit_z <- scale(x = data_2$netprofit)

data_2[which(data_2$netprofit_z < -3 | data_2$netprofit_z > 3),]

netprofit_outliers <- data_2[which(data_2$netprofit_z < -3 | data_2$netprofit_z > 3),]
```

By using `dput(netprofit_outliers)` it gives me 64 outlier values which are

```
> Deal = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No" )
```

So far I used;

```
ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

which gave me every value in the dataset. However I am only looking for a graph of the Deals that are specified 64 outliers.

I have also tried;

```
ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar(aes(netprofit_outliers)) + coord_flip()

ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = netprofit_outliers)) + coord_flip()

ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = data_2$netprofit_outliers)) + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, I was a dummy with this one.

data_2 is the overall data set. I wanted outliers instead of that.

To fix this, you would want to graph;

```
ggplot(netprofit_outliers, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

This is because rather than the entire dataset, you are looking at just the outlier dataset.

I also wish this could have been commented as I knew it was a simple problem that I just haven't had enough experience yet on how to do it.